Next.js - "window not defined" - Error thrown during deployment from context provider
I'm trying to build an e-commerce page with Next.js 14, which handles cart state in context API. I also want to save cart content in local storage to keep it persistent. So, when initializing the state in my context file, I want to get data from the local storage.
The solution works in development but throws "window is not defined error" during deployment on Vercel when generating static pages. I was trying different approaches and complained about localStorage itself not being defined (which is pretty obvious cause we cannot access window object anyway). Here is my /context/CartContext.jsx file:
"use client";
import { createContext, useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";

const useCartState = () => useState([]);

export const CartContext = createContext(null);

export const useCart = () => {
  const { cart, setCart } = useContext(CartContext);
  const cartHook = [cart, setCart];
  if (!cart) {
    alert("useCart must be used in a provider");
  }
  return cartHook;
};

export const useCartOpen = () => {
  const { cartOpen, setCartOpen } = useContext(CartContext);
  const cartOpenHook = [cartOpen, setCartOpen];
  return cartOpenHook;
};

const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [cart, setCart] = useCartState();
  const [cartOpen, setCartOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined" && window.localStorage) {
      const cart = localStorage.getItem("cart");
      if (cart) {
        setCart(JSON.parse(cart));
      }
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{ cart, setCart, cartOpen, setCartOpen }}>
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default CartProvider;

This is my file structure
app
├── api
├── diety
├── konsultacje
├── kontakt
├── podsumowanie
└── ui
context
├── CartContext.jsx

This is how I wrap application in a provider:
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="pl">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <CartProvider>
          <Navbar />
          <>{children}</>
          <Footer />
        </CartProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

This is an error message during production build (I tried to deploy it multiple times and it throws an error while generating pages with different url so it's not a problem with /konsultacje path):

As I understand, the code in a useEffect should run after the component is mounted which should make me sure that I can access window object and DOM APIs.
What I'm missing here? How can I handle localStorage within my provider correctly to make it work?
version :
 "next": "14.2.6",

This is how i tried to retrieve data initially:
const useCartState = () => useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart")) || []);

I was also wondering if using database would be better but as users on the page don't need to be logged in (only guest users) I thought that localstorage will be enough for this project.
